# How to calculate the sine function in Haskell?

Tags: c++, haskell, trigonometry, taylor-series

Here is my problem: I need a Haskell function that computes an approximation of the [sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine) of some number, using the associated Taylor serie ...

In C++ I wrote this:

```
double msin(double number, int counter = 0, double sum = 0)
{
    // sin(x) = x - (x'3 / 3!) + (x'5 / 5!) - (x'7 / 7!) + (x'9 / 9!)
    if (counter <= 20)
    {
        if (counter % 2 == 0)
            sum += mpow(number, counter * 2 + 1) / mfak(counter * 2 + 1) ;
        else
            sum -= mpow(number, counter * 2 + 1) / mfak(counter * 2 + 1) ;

        counter++;
        sum =  msin(number, counter, sum);

        return sum;
    }

    return (sum* 180.0 / _PI);
}
```

Now I am trying to do it in Haskell and I have no idea how... For now I was trying something like this (it doesn't really work, but it is work in progress ;) ):

This works:

```hs
mfak number = if number < 2
                    then 1
                    else number *( mfak (number -1 )) 


mpow number potenca = if potenca == 0
                        then 0
                        else if potenca == 1
                        then 1
                        else (number * (mpow number (potenca-1)))
```

This doesn't work:

```hs
msin :: Double -> Int -> Double -> Double                           
msin number counter sum = if counter <= 20
                                    then if counter `mod` 2==0
                                            then let sum = sum + (msin 1 (let counter = counter+1 in counter) sum) in sum 
                                            else let sum = sum + (msin 1 (let counter = counter+1 in counter) sum) in sum                                   
                                    else sum* 180.0 / 3.14
```

Updated....doesn't compile :/ "Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type` Int'"

```hs
msin :: Double -> Int -> Double -> Double                           
msin number counter sum = if counter <= 20
                                    then if counter `mod` 2==0
                                            then let sum' = sum + ((mpow number (counter*2+1))/(mfak counter*2+1)) in msin number (counter+1) sum'
                                            else let sum' = sum - ((mpow number (counter*2+1))/(mfak counter*2+1)) in msin number (counter+1) sum'                              
                                    else sum* 180.0 / 3.14
```

As you can see, the biggest problem is how to add something to "sum", increase "counter" and go in recursion again with these new values...

**P.S.** I am new to Haskell so try to explain your solution as much as you can please. I was reading some tutorials and that, but I can't find how to save the result of some expression into a value and then continue with other code after it... It just returns my value each time I try to do that, and I don't want that....

So thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you use English names for your variables, you are likely to increase your audience by several orders of magnitude. Just sayin'.

Comment: oki gonna change to english :) sorry didn't think of that before :)

Comment: If you have an `Int` and it expects a type `Double` use `fromIntegral`.

Comment: I'll look that fromIntegral solution later when i come home :) ty!

Answer (score 7):

I  would rework the algorithm a bit. First we can define the list of factorial inverses:

```hs
factorialInv :: [Double]
factorialInv = scanl (/) 1 [1..]  -- 1/0! , 1/1! , 1/2! , 1/3! , ...
```

Then, we follow with the sine coefficients:

```hs
sineCoefficients :: [Double]
sineCoefficients = 0 : 1 : 0 : -1 : sineCoefficients
```

Then, given `x`, we multiply both the above lists with the powers of `x`, pointwise:

```hs
powerSeries :: [Double]   -- ^ Coefficients
            -> Double     -- ^ Point x on which to compute the series
            -> [Double]   -- ^ Series terms
powerSeries cs x = zipWith3 (\a b c -> a * b * c) cs powers factorialInv
   where powers = iterate (*x) 1   -- 1 , x , x^2 , x^3 , ...
```

Finally, we take the first 20 terms and sum them up.

```hs
sine :: Double -> Double                   
sine = sum . take 20 . powerSeries sineCoefficients
 -- i.e., sine x = sum (take 20 (powerSeries sineCoefficients x))
```

Comment: Thanks, you reminded me there is `iterate`. But for me, I'd try to avoid zero harmonics (_x²_, _x⁴_ ...) at all.

Comment: @firegurafiku Me too, but I liked the generality of the `powerSeries` function.

Comment: You could define a custom multiplication operator that checks for zero coefficients and exits lazily, which would avoid calculating the x^n when the nth coefficient is zero.

Comment: @luqui Using `iterate` will cause `x^n` to be computed anyway when `x^(n+1)` is demanded. We might save a multiplication, though if we used `a * (b * c)` and `a` is null.

Comment: Thanks for this idea :) i think i can use some of this in some other assigments but in this one i should not use any "global" lists etc. all the magic must happen in one function with recursion (the assigment ask that from me so i must do as it says)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is expressions like `let stevec = stevec+1 in stevec`.  Haskell is not an imperative language.  This does not add one to `stevec`.  Instead it defines `stevec` to be a number that is one more than itself.  No such number exists, thus you will get an infinite loop or, if you are lucky, a crash.

Instead of

```
stevec++;
vsota =  msin(stevilo, stevec, vsota);
```

You should use something like

```
let stevec' = stevec + 1
in  msin stevilo stevec' vsota
```

or just

```
msin stevilo (stevec + 1) vsota
```

(There's also something here that I don't understand.  You are going to need `mpow` and `mfak`.  Where are they?)

Answer (score 1):

```
As you can see the biggest problem is how to add something to "vsota",
```

In a functional language you would use recursion here - the variable `vstota` is implemented as a function parameter which is passed from call to call as a list is processed.

For example, to sum a list of numbers, we would write something like:

```
sum xs = go 0 xs
  where go total [] = total
        go total (x:xs) = go (total+x) xs
```

In an imperative language `total` would be a variable which gets updated. Here is is a function parameter which gets passed to the next recursive call to `go`.

In your case, I would first write a function which generates the terms of the power series:

```
sinusTerms n x = ... -- the first n terms of x - (x'3 / 3!) + (x'5 / 5!) - (x'7 / 7!) ...
```

and then use the `sum` function above:

```
sinus n x = sum (sinusTerms n x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use recursive lists definitions to get `[x, x^3, x^5 ...]` and `[1, 1/3!, 1/5! ...]` infinite sequences. When they are done, the rest is to multiply their items each by other and take the sum.

```haskell
sinus count x = sum (take count $ zipWith (*) ifactorials xpowers)
    where xpowers     = x : map ((x*x)*) xpowers 
          ifactorials = 1 : zipWith (/) ifactorials [i*(i+1) | i <- [2, 4 .. ]]
```

Also, it would be better to define `xpowers = iterate ((x*x)*) x`, as it seems to be much more readable.

Comment: I cannot test the code in GHCI right now, so there may be some mistakes in it.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve tried to follow your conventions as much as I could. For `mfak` and `mpow`, you should avoid using `if` as it is clearer to write them using pattern matching :

```
mfak :: Int -> Int
mfak 0 = 1
mfak 1 = 1
mfak n = n * mfak (n - 1)

mpow :: Double -> Int -> Double
mpow _ 0 = 1
mpow x 1 = x
mpow x p = x * mpow x (p - 1)
```

Before calculating the sinus, we create a list of coefficients `[(sign, power, factorial)]` :

```
x - (x^3 / 3!) + (x^5 / 5!) - (x^7 / 7!) + (x^9 / 9!)
→ [(1,1,1), (-1,3,6), (1,5,120), (-1,7,5040), (1,9,362880)]
```

The list is created infinite by a list comprehension. First we zip the lists `[1,-1,1,-1,1,-1...]` and `[1,3,5,7,9,11...]`. This gives us the list `[(1,1), (-1,3), (1,5), (-1,7)...]`. From this list, we create the final list `[(1,1,1), (-1,3,6), (1,5,120), (-1,7,5040)...]`:

```
sinCoeff :: [(Double, Int, Double)]
sinCoeff = [ (fromIntegral s, i, fromIntegral $ mfak i)
           | (s, i) <- zip (cycle [1, -1]) [1,3..]]
```

(`cycle` repeats a list indefinitely, `[1,3..]` creates an infinite list which starts at 1 with a step of 2)

Finally, the `msin` function is near the definition. It also uses a list comprehension to achieve its goeal (note that I kept the `* 180 / pi` though I’m not sure it should be there. Haskell knows pi).

```
msin :: Int -> Double -> Double
msin n x = 180 * sum [ s * mpow x p / f | (s, p, f) <- take n sinCoeff] / pi
```

(`take n sinCoeff` returns the first `n` elements of a list)

You may try the previous code with the following :

```
main = do
    print $ take 10 sinCoeff
    print $ msin 5 0.5
    print $ msin 10 0.5
```

Comment: Well im new to Haskell so i'm still learning :) i'll change those functions as u said, but this List solutions doesn't work in my case (i need to do it with recursion without lists or any global variables) but ty anyway :D You explained it and i like that because i actually understand most of your code (after few days of learning Haskell) :)

Answer (score 0):

The expression is of the form x*P(x<sup>2</sup>).

For maximal efficiency, the polynomial in x<sup>2</sup> must be evaluated using [*the Horner rule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) rather than computing the powers of x<sup>2</sup> separately.

The coefficient serie with the factorial values can be expressed recursively in Haskell, just like is commonly done for the Fibonacci series. Using the `ghci` interpreter as our testbed, we have:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> 
 λ> nextCoeffs d c = c : (nextCoeffs (d+1) ((-c)/(fromIntegral $ (2*d+2)*(2*d+3))))
 λ> 
 λ> allCoeffs = nextCoeffs 0 1.0
 λ>
```

where d is the depth inside the serie and c the current coefficient.

Sanity check: the coefficient at depth 3 must be the inverse of 7!

```
 λ> 
 λ> 1.0 /(allCoeffs !! 3)
 -5040.0
 λ>
```

The Horner rule can be rendered in Haskell thru the [foldr1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:foldr1) library function.

As is customary in Haskell, I take the liberty to put the term count as the leftmost argument because it is the one most likely to be held constant. This is for currying (partial evaluation) purposes.

So we have:

```
 λ> :{
|λ>  msin count x = let { s = x*x ;  cs = take count allCoeffs ;
|λ>                       stepFn c acc = acc*s + c ; }
|λ>                 in  x * (foldr1 stepFn cs)
|λ> :}
```

Sanity checks, taking 20 terms:

```
 λ> 
 λ> pi
 3.141592653589793
 λ>
 λ> msin 20 (pi/6)
 0.49999999999999994
 λ> 
 λ> msin 20 (pi/2)
 1.0
 λ>
```

**Side note 1**: final multiplication by 180 / π is only of interest for *inverse* trigonometric functions.

**Side note 2**: in practice, to get a reasonably fast convergence, one should reduce the input variable x into the [-π,+π] interval using the  periodicity of the sine function.